# What do the new sizes of the "Simulated Metrics" in Interface Builder for iOS 5 for iPad mean?

Tags: ipad, interface-builder, ios5

In Interface Builder (iOS 5/iPad), under "Simulated Metrics" of a view controller, I found two sizes that aren't very clear to me:

- Page sheet
- Form sheet

The page sheet in landscape has a height of 100% and a width of ±70%. The form sheet has a height of ±70% and a width of ±50%. Are they both used for modal views?

Can somebody show me the right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference…

- **Page sheet**: a large modal view used by Mail when composing e-mails.
- **Form sheet**: a small modal view used by Settings when managing an iTunes Store account.